# How to create a new sheet and write some data in the existing excel using selenium java

Tags: apache-poi

I tried the below code.

But it overwrite the existing sheet.

```
File f= new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Exceldata.xls");   

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();         
    HSSFSheet worksheet= workbook.createSheet("Sheet4");        
    HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(1);
    HSSFCell cell= row.createCell(1);
    cell.setCellValue("admin");     

enter code here


    workbook.write(f);
    workbook.close();
```

Comment: How does it relate to `Selenium`?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileInputStream instead of File and and object of XSSFWorkbook
I hope this function may help you,

```
public static void write(){
       try
       {
           FileInputStream myxls = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Exceldata.xls"  );
           HSSFWorkbook studentsSheet = new HSSFWorkbook(myxls);
           workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(myxls );
           workbook.createSheet(sheetname);
           HSSFSheet worksheet = studentsSheet.getSheetAt(0);
           a=worksheet.getLastRowNum();
           System.out.println(a);
           Row row = worksheet.createRow(++a);
           row.createCell(1).setCellValue("");
           myxls.close();
           FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\test\\resources\\Exceldata.xls"));  
           //write changes
           workbook.write(output_file );

           studentsSheet.write(output_file);
           output_file.close();
           System.out.println(" is successfully written");
       }
```

Try calling this function from main maethod,

```
public static void main(String args[])
   {
       write();
   }
```

Possible duplicate of [Append Data in existing Excel file using apache poi in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220400/append-data-in-existing-excel-file-using-apache-poi-in-java) and
[How to add new sheets to existing excel workbook using apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459181/how-to-add-new-sheets-to-existing-excel-workbook-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Thanks Ashish for the reply. But does your code create a new sheet. My requirement is to create a new sheet in the already existing excel .

Comment: To brief my requirement : i have a excel named "Records" which has a sheet named Sheet1 and having some data. Now i want to create a new sheet named "Sheet2" in the same excel and wanted to write some data

Comment: I tried the above links that you have given and it still didn't worked for me. So i posted the question here

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out the solution. i had used poi jar 4.0 in which i could not succeed in writing data. I then downgraded the jar version to 3.14 and i works perfectly